# Find last value before blank relative to cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, draggable

I have a data-set with a large number of smaller tables arranged in two columns.

To do some calculations, in each row i need to find the total for the smaller table that row belongs to, below is a picture to illustrate.

[image]

Is there a formula I can use that can be dragged to populate every row in the data-set? there are hundreds of tables in each column so having to manually set the total cell for each row/section would take hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in H3 then fill down.

```
=IF(B3<>"", INDEX(C3:C$9999, MATCH("total", B3:B$9999, 0)), "")
```

Comment: lateral thinking

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much, just saved me oceans of mindless work!